# ul link missfire when clicked

Tags: html, css

I have some quick links and for some reason it miss fires the link will not go to section when clicked.

```
<div class="quick-links">    
    <ul id="quick-links">
        <li class="section1 active"><a href="#section1"><span>section1</span></a></li>
        <li class="section2"><a href="#section2"><span>section2</span></a></li>
        <li class="section3"><a href="#section3"><span>section3</span></a></li>     
    </ul>      
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/codiman/pen/YNOoPM

I want to click the circles for them to designated section

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: that is my code jsfiddle is a third party site and its added here daily

Comment: There are several things wrong with that statement. 1. Your code is on CodePen, not JSFiddle. 2. JSFiddle is not "added here daily". If you've seen your code copied here in the past, it's because someone was kind enough to copy it here for you. But it's something you should do yourself. 3. The whole point of my comment is that it should not be on a third-party site.

Comment: Because you set in your css `pointer-events: none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've disabled your `<a>` tag setting `pointer-events: none`. If you consider text also clickable there is simple solution (by removing `pointer-events: none` and placing circle inside clickable area):

http://codepen.io/themeler/pen/ggBOKr

```css
.quick-links ul li a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
        padding-right: 65px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the property pointer-events set to "none", therefore the a tag doesn't catch the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Click event is intercepted by li rather than a tag.

I have made some changes to the code I hope you will restyle it.

```
<a href="#section1"><ul>
    <li class=""><span>section1</span></li>
    </ul></a>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/r0rq6x3y/